# Not allowing user to enter the number 1 as the first digit in a UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, nsrange

I have a UITextField where the user can enter in their phone number. I need the phone number to be in the following format: 5567289223 and not like this with an extra 1 at the beginning: 15567289223.

I already have an if statement setup so if the number is greater than 10 digits or less than 10 digits it will throw an error.

The only final problem I don't know how to solve is if the user tries putting an extra 1 in the beginning of the phone number.

I need to setup an if statement so that if the first character in the phone number is a "1" we will throw an error, or an even easier possible solution would be to use `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` so that if it's the first number they are typing in the UITextField then it cannot be a 1.

Someone gave me this solution earlier for controlling which characters are allowed to be typed into a UITextField: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22265084/3344977

I have been trying to modify it so that it will not allow the number "1" to be the first number typed into the UITextField but I cannot get it to work properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified the example you want to use as per your need, you can check it out

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
if(textField==self.testTextField&&range.location==0)
{
    if ([string hasPrefix:@"1"])
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: This isn't working. I am able to type "1" and when I do and try to type the 2nd number the app crashes and gives me this error: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: @MartinR I actually need to be able to enter the digit 1, just not as the very first digit being entered into the uitextfield. Anywhere after is fine.

Comment: i Have edited my post and also tested teh same.. working for me! :)

Comment: This might fail if 1) you hit the "delete" key (because `string` is the empty string in that case and `characterAtIndex:0` will crash , or 2) you use copy/paste to replace the field contents (because `textField.text` is not empty in that case).

Comment: @MartinR Fixing for that aswell, Thanks! And fixed one more bug if teh user manually goes to position 1 and changes the text replaced it teextfield.text.length with range.location!

Comment: That's much better now! Note that you can simplify the character check to `if ([string hasPrefix:@"1"]) ...` .

Comment: aaah.. That can be much more easier! :) Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

See this answer,

[UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)

i would setup an event handler like how it's mentioned in that example. and then an if statement inside the selector:

```
if([textField.text length] == 1 && [textField.text isEqualToString:@"1"]){

     //Do something.
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For Swift

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{

 if textField == self.txtFieldName && range.location == 0
    {
        if string.hasPrefix("1"){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true

}
```